# How to send email from localhost

Tags: php, apache, sendmail

I have set  up my sendmail settings as follows:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=tls
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypass
```

The email is not being sent, although in debug.log file it shows as "Connected" and after that it shows:

```
15/08/25 11:34:59 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
15/08/25 11:34:59 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
15/08/25 11:34:59 >> QUIT<EOL>
```

And then some strange characters. After which it shows Connection Closed Gracefully.

Can somebody help me with this error?

The code I am using to test it is simple as follows:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Localhost - ' . $_SESSION['org']->legal_name . '<' . $sender_email . '>' . "\r\n";
$subject = 'subject';
$contents = 'contents of email';
mail($to, $subject, $contents, $headers);
```

Comment: the code is simple just to test, i have added that in the question.

Comment: Do you have mod_ssl enabled?

Comment: Yes I have the following enabled in my php.ini
extension=php_openssl.dll
and it is enabled properly